# Writing into a file residing in Xcode project directory

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am currently writing code that writes data (data is generated from an HTTP response) to an xml file that resides in the Xcode project directory (Application bundle).Unfortunately I wasn't able to write into an xml file that resides in the Xcode project, So, I tried the same code and I just modified the file path to point to an xml file that resides in the desktop (I choose a different location in order to investigate the issue further) and surprisingly it worked where a simple string is written to the xml file. I read some posts saying that we can't write to a file in the App bundle as there is a limitation in this aspect for the Iphone. Is that true ? And if so, is there any alternative. I would really appreciate if anyone has an insight on this issue and could help. Note that I declared an error variable and tried to see if I can log any error message, but the debugger didn't enter the if statement (and hence no writing error is caught). Below is the sample code that I wrote:

```
//writing to a file
  NSString *file_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"xml"];
  NSString *dummy = @"Hello World!!\n"; 
  NSFileManager *filemanger;
  NSError *writingError = nil;
  filemanger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  if ([filemanger fileExistsAtPath:file_path] == YES)
    NSLog (@"File do exist!!!");
  else
    NSLog (@"File is not found!!!");


BOOL sucess = [dummy writeToFile:file_path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&writingError];
if(!sucess)
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to write to the file");
}

if (writingError) {
    NSLog(@"Fail: %@", [writingError localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS the app bundle is signed and readonly so that is off limits.  Instead there is a file area and one of the directories is Documents, that is a really good place to save data.

Here is a code fragment that demonstrates accessing the Documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```